# Slideshow Gallery with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, image, gallery, slideshow

Hi there I want to create Slideshow Gallery using PHP and Javascript.

I have a camera setup at my house that is sending picture in JPG format every time when motion is detected.

I want to be able when I visit:

camera.example.com/

Pictures from last 3 Days to start to appear in A slideshow fast.

The structure is like this:

```
camera.example.com
-snap (where the pictures from the camera are uploaded when motion is detected).
```

code of index.php:

```
<?

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname="snap") {
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
echo '<img src="snap/'.$file .'" /><br />';
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo '<a href=./slideshow.php>WHEN ALL OF THE PICTURES LOAD UP << CLICK ME >></a><br /><br /><br />';
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
?>
```

code of getimages.php:

```
<?
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname="snap") {
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
?>
```

code of: slideshow.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Timelapse</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000" align="center">
<script src="getimages.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "snap/"+galleryarray[curimg])
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 500)
}
</script>
<div>
<img id="slideshow" src="loader.gif" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this, it doesn't neccesery have to be even my code.. all I want is to work so if someone gives me a better alternative it's fine.

I want to be able to view what happen on my Front yard during the past 3 days fast, without having to Open all pictures one by one.

I want them SORTED from the Newest to the Oldest.

I used the following tutorial to do this: [Slideshow Gallery loading all images in directory](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml)

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Martin, I think your question may be on a fast track to being closed...(sorry to say)

Comment: Why sir, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you display your attempt(s) of doing this and explain the issue you're having with the current source code? Or is this a request for someone to do the work for you?

Comment: StackOverflow is for problems with code, you have provided no code or attempts.

Comment: I do have a code I tried but it's not working so I thought it would be better idea may be someone more knowledgeable then me can point me in the right direction

Comment: Further, asking for people to give you code for free is not the best idea, the SO community is here to help developers when they are stuck, not to do all the work for you.

Comment: Just post what you have so we can try and spot where you are going wrong. People will be happy to help if you have made at least a valid attempt.

Comment: No source code = nothing to debug and not knowing the setup for this will make the question too broad. I can think of multiple ways you could have this set up, but without that information it leaves people guessing and we don't come here to guess. We come here to debug/fix/explain. Could you edit your question with the relevant source code and explain the problem you're having.

Comment: I don't feel you're going to learn anything if i post source code so what i will do is give you a simple way to set this up. Have the date of the snapshot in the image name. Example: 15042015_SomerandomID.jpg. Use your php to get the current date, -3 days from that, use a if condition to place the images into an array within that date range, have that array return to your gallery. A simple if  less than condition will do it.

Comment: If I could have done I would have done it without asking here

Comment: Research how to get the current date and how to minus x-amount of days using php, you can use `explode('_',$file);` to split the image name into an array, use the first array as that will hold the date stamp. Use a if condition to compare the dates. I'm assuming you know how to use the if condition as you're already using one in your existing source code. If you research that, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: We are talking about 1000 pictures, I don't wanna load the server with any sort of calculations, I prefer to be done in Javascript... the only thing I need is all the pictures to be sorted by Time or Date with NEWEST first I don't want to deal with any Functions involving EXPLODE with PHP.

Comment: If you're not open to editing the existing source code then how can you be open to other methods? **it doesn't neccesery have to be even my code.. all I want is to work so if someone gives me a better alternative it's fine.** and `explode()` is the same as using `split();` in javascript. Also 1000's of images makes no difference as the php isn't loading the images, it's nothing but a string/text.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the way your images are saved to **date**_something.jpg then you can use the following. You will have to work out how to place this into your own source code, I wouldn't want to do all the work for you.

- If it isn't possible for you to change the way image names are saved, please edit your question and display how your images are saved.

Date format: Year Month Day => 20150415

The following is going by today's date: **15th April 2015.**

```
<?php
// Temporary Array of image names (demo use).
$ImageNames=array("20150415_one.jpg","20150414_two.jpg","20150413_three.jpg","20150412_four.jpg","20150411_five.jpg","20150410_six.jpg");
// Empty Array - To hold image names within date range
$ReturnImages=array();
// For each value in $ImageNames array
foreach ($ImageNames as $Image) {
// Split the image name to get the date
    $Uploaded=explode("_",$Image);
/*
$Uploaded[0] => Date
$Uploaded[1] => one.jpg / two.jpg / three.jpg
*/   
// If image date is equal to or greater than. 
    if($Uploaded[0]>=date('Ymd', strtotime('-3 day'))){
        array_push($ReturnImages, $Image);
    }
}
/* $ReturnImages now holds all the images within the date range (Last 3 days) */

//*********************************************************
// This foreach isn't required, this is to show the results
foreach ($ReturnImages as $display) {
echo $display.' ';
}
//*********************************************************
?>
```

> **Output:** 20150415_one.jpg 20150414_two.jpg 20150413_three.jpg 20150412_four.jpg

`20150411_five.jpg` & `20150410_six.jpg` will not return because the dates are more than 3 days old.

As you can see I have added comments to explain every step, if you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!